# FitNesse - Wiki editing - Syntax Error with underline

Tags: eclipse, syntax, syntax-error, wiki, fitnesse

Is it possible, or is an Option available to get a Red underline in form of a Syntax Error just like in coding?

If i delete a Symbol, nothing happened in the editing. There is not a Red underline with waves or something like that. But it is very helpful to know, that something is changed and i know that. 
We want to work in Eclipse for editing in the Content.

It is for our FitNesse Wiki page.

Thanks!

Comment: For intellij (also for community edition) there is a plugin that checks fixture methods and scenarios. I don't believe it checks symbols

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use code highlighting and syntax checks, I would recommend you use IntelliJ Community edition with the FitNesse plugin.